# How do I mix coroutines with callback-style implementations properly in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, firebase-authentication, callback, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to use Firebase Authentication in a MVVM architecture in my app. I am using Kotlin and coroutines and after implementing firebase callbacks in my suspend functions I have faced some conceptual problems related to asynchronous execution of the Firebase callbacks and suspend functions.

I am trying to implement the Google Signin with Firebase in Kotlin by following the MVVM architecture. So I have designed an AuthViewModel which sends the received token (from Google One-tap) to the AuthRepository by calling the following suspend function:

```
.
.
.
suspend fun getGoogleSignInResult(token: String): Envelope<AuthUserInfo> {
        return withContext(defaultDispatcher) {
            when(val response = authRemoteDataSource.getGoogleSignInResult(token)) {
                is Envelope.Success -> {
                    Envelope.Success(AuthUserInfo(response.data!!, null))
                }
                else -> {
                    Envelope.Error(response.tag!!, response.message)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This function, dispatches to the defaultDispatcher and calls authRemoteDataSource.getGoogleSignInResult(token) in my remote data source (authRemoteDataSource) and gets suspended. Then authRemoteDataSource gets the control and dispatches to the ioDispatcher as follows:

```
.
.
.
suspend fun getGoogleSignInResult(token: String): Envelope<FirebaseUser> {
        return withContext(ioDispatcher) {
            // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
            // with Firebase.
            var user: FirebaseUser? = null
            val job = launch {
                val firebaseCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(token, null)
                auth.signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential)
                    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d("TEST", "signInWithCredential:success")
                            user = auth.currentUser
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            
                            Log.w("TEST", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                        }
                    }
            }
            job.join() // callbacks are not synchronous so we must wait for the job
            user?.let { Envelope.Success(user!!) }
                ?: Envelope.Error(Envelope.Tag.NON_CACHED_EXCEPTION)
        }
    }
```

But this function fails since it returns before the assigned callback to the addOnCompleteListener gets completed; user is NULL and it will return Envelope.Error(Envelope.Tag.NON_CACHED_EXCEPTION). It seems like  the call to signInWithCredential is asynchronous and the job is not waiting for it. The question is that:

1. Can I force Firebase to execute synchronously?

By the way, I changed above code to the following and I was expecting that shouldn't work either:

```
.
.
.
suspend fun getGoogleSignInResult(token: String): Envelope<FirebaseUser> {
        var user: FirebaseUser? = null
        val job =  withContext(ioDispatcher) {
            // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
            // with Firebase.
            val firebaseCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(token, null)
            auth.signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("TEST", "signInWithCredential:success")
                        user = auth.currentUser
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w("TEST", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    }
                }
        }

        // Return
        job.await() // addOnCompleteListener is not synchronous so we must wait for the job
        return user?.let { Envelope.Success(user!!) }
            ?: Envelope.Error(Envelope.Tag.NON_CACHED_EXCEPTION)
    }
```

but surprisingly, it works properly; it waits for the callback addOnCompleteListener to get completed and then returns Envelope.Success(user!!).

2. Do you have any idea why above code works properly?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Callbacks can be turned into suspend functions using `suspendCancellableCoroutine`, but Firebase already provides suspend functions you can use instead of callbacks. You can Google search how to use them—I don’t use Firebase myself. The `job.await()` function you used is a Firebase suspend function, but you shouldn’t combine it with the callback since that’s really convoluted. `await()`directly returns the result synchronously. “Job” is a bad name for your variable, since it implies a launched coroutine. It’s a “task” returned synchronously from the `withContext` block.

Comment: You can `await()` a Task instead of giving it listeners. You don’t need withContext since it’s not blocking to get your task reference.

Comment: have you try with callbackFlow?
https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html

Comment: Maybe this [approach](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Answer (score 0):

I used **suspendCoroutine** to combine the callbacks with the suspend function. Now, I have changed my code as follows:

```
suspend fun getGoogleSignInResult(token: String): Envelope<FirebaseUser> {
    return withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        return@withContext suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            val firebaseCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(token, null)
            auth.signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    continuation.resume(Envelope.Success(it.user!!))
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    val res: Envelope<FirebaseUser> =
                        Envelope.Error(Envelope.Tag.NON_CACHED_EXCEPTION)
                    continuation.resume(res)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

This works properly. I used *addOnSuccessListener* and *addOnFailureListener* to get the result instead of *addOnCompleteListener*. By using **suspendCoroutine**, the function *getGoogleSignInResult* is supposed to get suspended until **continuation.resume(res)** is called in one of the the callbacks. Then it resumes and returns *res*.